# Dynamically populating a dropdownlist based on selected value in another dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two dropdown lists, where one is populated on page load and the other should only be populated when a value is selected in the first one.  The first dropdown list is defined as:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID = "base_ddl" runat="server" ToolTip="Base" OnSelectedIndexChanged = "BaseSelected">
//  snip...
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Then, the second dropdown list (`secondary_ddl`) is populated in the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` method, `BaseSelected`.

```
    public void BaseSelected(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (base_ddl.SelectedValue == "-1")
        {
            secondary_ddl.Visible = false;
        }
        else 
        {
            secondary_ddl.Items.Clear();

            // extract information to populate dropdown here
            // snip.
            IList<InfoContainer> info = getInfoBasedOnSelected(base_ddl.Value);

            foreach (InfoContainer i in info)
            {
                secondary_ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem(i.name, i.value));
            }
        }
    }
```

This doesn't work, which leads to this question: why?  How can I dynamically update that dropdown from the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` function for the other dropdown?

Comment: first of all you dont need Databind on second dropdown as you are adding items to it. and check your list does it have any value?

Comment: @Samim I didn't think so, that was added when debugging.  I'm positive that items get added to the list (stepped through and saw them).  Removed that line of code to avoid that coming up again, thanks.

Comment: What does "This doesn't work" mean? What do you expect and what do you see? Does the first dropdown have AutoPostBack set to true?

Comment: @Igor The UI dropdown list doesn't populate, even though I see the line "secondary_ddl.Items.Add(...)" being called multiple times.

Comment: Then something else must be removing items from it - either server- or client-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st set `AutoPostBack="True"` property of `base_ddl`

and then

```
secondary_ddl.Items.Clear();
IList<InfoContainer> info = getInfoBasedOnSelected(base_ddl.Value);
secondary_ddl.DataTextField = "name";
secondary_ddl.DataValueField = "value";
secondary_ddl.DataSource = info;
secondary_ddl.DataBind();
```

Comment: AutoPostBack was the required attribute.  Adding that solved the issues.  Thanks